# How to load old PHP versions for PhpStorm, but not install them on your local

Tags: php, compilation, phpstorm, interpreter

I looked for similar questions and could not find any information about the step I am hung up on in the documentation or here on Stack Overflow -- where is the PHP executable located after compiling PHP for inclusion into PhpStorm? I've included the context below in case I have an "XY problem" ( http://xyproblem.info ).

I am troubleshooting some software for a friend -- and this friend is using PHP 5.5. I know, friends don't let friends use outdated software. I am rewriting a chunk to be friendly with newer versions of PHP.

I've downloaded the PHP interpreter source for 5.5.38 (or something similar)... I had to install some XML dev package (Kubuntu 16.04). But the `./configure` and following `make` and `make test` worked fine -- as far as I know I have files ready for a `make install`... but, I like the PHP 7.x I have installed and would like to keep my local as such and did not issue the `make install` command for that reason.

I am in the "Settings", I selected the "Languages & Frameworks" section, similarly I went into the PHP subsection.

In the Interpreters window, I've added an option labeled "PHP 5.5 local". My installed php executable is `/usr/bin/php7.0` as an example from the "PHP 7.0 local option"...

What or where is the PHP 5.5 interpreter in my compiled source?

Comment: I had considered editing the Makefile so that when I ran make install, that the files would not be put in the regular installation directories...

Comment: For now I am just going to spin up a php5.5 Docker container... But, still curious if I can just point to a compiled PHP executable without installing.

Comment: Yes, you can point, why not? PHP binary is the only thing that PhpStorm needs.

Comment: @VladLuchansky I agree, just edited the question to show the executables in my working directory for PHP5.5 after running ./configure, make, and make test.

Comment: In my working directory php-5.5.38, there is `sapi/cgi/php-cgi` .

Comment: `sapi/cgi/php-cgi` when I tried to run it, it complained about the ini file (supposedly in /usr/local/lib per `sapi/cgi/php-cgi -ini`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[brad@T540p php-5.5.38]$ sapi/cgi/php-cgi -c /brad/home/PHP-Versions/php-5.5.38/php.ini index.php
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.38
Content-type: text/html

I did it!
[brad@T540p php-5.5.38]$
```

So, go download the php version you want. Uncompress the source.
Go into the directory with the source files.

```
./configure --with-config-file-path="/home/brad/PHP-Versions/php-5.5.38"

make

cp php.ini-development php.ini
cp php.ini-development ./sapi/cgi/
```

The first php.ini is the one you specify in the ./configure and I used with the -c switch on the command line. However, PHPStorm seems to find the sapi/cgi/php.ini configuration... whatever, I don't care, it works.

At that point you should be able to point PHPStorm at `.../php-5.5.38/sapi/cgi/php-cgi` and it will recognize it locally without actually installing this version of PHP it into your machine in the usual places & configurations.

Since I wanted PHP v5.5.38, I named my directory php-5.5.38 as noted above. You may need to make adjustments if you have other preferences on naming your directories otherwise.